# How to structure the particion key in a cassandra table for user following

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, database-partitioning

I want to make a table, where users follow other users. In this table I need an userID for the following user and an userID for the followed user. In the case that there are some users, that get followed by hundreds of thousands of users, so it is too large to store them efficiently in a collection.

How can I model it, that all of the followers of a single user don't end up in the same partition? Before realizing this problem I wanted to use either the following user ID oder followed user ID as the partition key, but then there should be a hot-partition problem.

Could I use a composite partition key with following user ID and followed user ID to solve the hot-partition problem? What else could save this problem?

My 2 main queries are to get all following users of an user and get all followed users of an user.
If i user a composite partition key with those 2 IDs, can I even query the things above? Or do I need to query with both IDs and so it is not possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem in social graphs where certain personalities have millions more followers than everyone else. I tend to use Taylor Swift and Barrack Obama as examples.

A lot of social platforms handle this "super-nodes" issue by isolating them in a separate data store so that the main store doesn't queue up when someone traverses a super-node.

This does mean that you need to handle this in your app such that your app needs to check the user against a reference table of super-users/super-nodes so it then does lookups in sub-table(s) instead of the main table. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at bucketing solution. In Bucketing, you introduce an additional key to be a part of your partition key. For example, you can have your data model like this

```
CREATE TABLE user_followers (
user_id int,
bucket_id  int,
follower_id int, 
user_name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, bucket_id)));
```

Here user_id and bucket_id is the partition key. To find all the partitions you should know your bucket_ids beforehand.